# Windows Forms Browser Skeleton (C#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was wondering if anyone knows of an existing sample or an approach to achieve the desired functionality.

Basically, what I'm looking for is a web browser like skeleton. The idea is that the main screen of my application is shown in the left tab.  This tab can never be closed.  On this screen is an overview of various application components such as activities, events, contacts, etc.

When the user clicks on a specific contact/event/activity a new tab is created and auto-focused.  The user can view and edit the information.  When they are done they can close the tab.

The ability to have multiple tabs open is important.

Also, keyboard shortcuts to easily navigate between tabs would be great, but not absolutely essential at this point.

Note: I don't need to access any web content.

Really what I'm looking for, at least what I think I'm looking for, is a shell of a modern web browser.  Does something like this exist?  Is there a good approach to building such an application?

Note: I'm new to Windows GUI development, so I apologize if this is a rudimentary question.  I was unable to find anything meaningful while searching MSDN and other resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like is not really a Web Browser shell at all, simply the relative appearance of one functionality-wise.

What you can do is use a `TabControl` control. This can be altered to suit your needs quite perfectly in my view.

An example of a modified `TabControl` is as follows: [ [From here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/flattabcontrol.aspx) ]

[image: The Code Project]

There are a number of things that can be done with a `TabControl` (as with any other component) to make it suit what you need.

Here are some links that you may find helpful:

- [Flat Tab Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/flattabcontrol.aspx) - As per the picture
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx)
- [Video on using a Tab Control](http://blog.codebeach.com/2009/07/using-tab-control-in-c.html)
- [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/tabcontroltutorial11302005235835pm/tabcontroltutorial.aspx)